# How to install HDF5 version 1.10.5 on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5

I am using pycharm 2019.2 and I get the error below when trying to run this code :

```
import nltk
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json

from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()


with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
```

Error :

```
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
                  Configured on: 2019-03-04
                  Configured by: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
                    Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
              Uname information: Windows
                       Byte sex: little-endian
             Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5

Compiling Options:
------------------
                     Build Mode: 
              Debugging Symbols: 
                        Asserts: 
                      Profiling: 
             Optimization Level: 

Linking Options:
----------------
                      Libraries: 
  Statically Linked Executables: OFF
                        LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
                     H5_LDFLAGS: 
                     AM_LDFLAGS: 
                Extra libraries: 
                       Archiver: 
                         Ranlib: 

Languages:
----------
                              C: yes
                     C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe 19.0.24218.1
                       CPPFLAGS: 
                    H5_CPPFLAGS: 
                    AM_CPPFLAGS: 
                         CFLAGS:  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
                      H5_CFLAGS: 
                      AM_CFLAGS: 
               Shared C Library: YES
               Static C Library: YES

                        Fortran: OFF
               Fortran Compiler:  
                  Fortran Flags: 
               H5 Fortran Flags: 
               AM Fortran Flags: 
         Shared Fortran Library: YES
         Static Fortran Library: YES

                            C++: ON
                   C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe 19.0.24218.1
                      C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
                   H5 C++ Flags: 
                   AM C++ Flags: 
             Shared C++ Library: YES
             Static C++ Library: YES

                            JAVA: OFF
                   JAVA Compiler:  

Features:
---------
                   Parallel HDF5: OFF
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: 
              Large Parallel I/O: 
              High-level library: ON
                    Threadsafety: OFF
             Default API mapping: v110
  With deprecated public symbols: ON
          I/O filters (external):  DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
                             MPE: 
                      Direct VFD: 
                         dmalloc: 
  Packages w/ extra debug output: 
                     API Tracing: OFF
            Using memory checker: OFF
 Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
          Function Stack Tracing: OFF
       Strict File Format Checks: OFF
    Optimization Instrumentation: 
Bye...

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

I am using python 3.6 and have already downloaded HDF5 1.10.5 using pip and using conda install. But when I enter my anaconda python configuration the highest available HDF5 version is 1.10.4 and from this error message I suppose I need to have the 1.10.5 version to run properly.
 I want to know how to download the HDF5 1.10.5 so that I can run the code normally.

Comment: This may happen when you miss configure the `HDF5_DIR` path directory.

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get the right version with conda, but for me it worked to do

`pip install h5py --upgrade --no-dependencies --force`

Comment: I had tried everything on net, but worked for me. thanks