# Alternating errors using HDF5 library and h5py module

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, hdf5, h5py

I have created a CNN model and am trying to save it as an .h5 file, then later load the model. I am working within a virtual environment in Anaconda. The funny thing is, I can do everything in a Jupyter Notebook within the virtual environment with no problem. However, when I try running it in the terminal (loading the model, then evaluating it), it does not work. I am having a set of alternating errors which have solutions on the web, but these solutions either lead to dead ends, or lead to the other error.

The first error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MNIST.py", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "MNIST.py", line 62, in main
    evaluate_model()
  File "MNIST.py", line 54, in evaluate_model
    model = models.load_model('final_model.h5')
  File "C:\Users\Josh Cruz\Documents\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Josh Cruz\Documents\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 582, in load_model
    if H5Dict.is_supported_type(filepath):
  File "C:\Users\Josh Cruz\Documents\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\io_utils.py", line 209, in is_supported_type
    isinstance(path, h5py.Group) or
AttributeError: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'Group'
```

I haven't found a specific fix for fixing `Attribute Error: module 'h5py' has no attribute 'Group'`, but I did find [similar issues online](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1360) whose solutions suggest that I should update h5py to 2.10.0 using `conda install -c conda-forge h5py`. This makes sense to me, as groups seem to be part of the 2.10.0 h5py documentation.

Upon installing this comes up:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
h5py-2.9.0                 |nompi_py36h9dfa0df_1103         909 KB  conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         909 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  h5py               conda-forge/win-64::h5py-2.9.0-nompi_py36h9dfa0df_1103

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  certifi              pkgs/main::certifi-2019.11.28-py36_1 --> conda-forge::certifi-2019.11.28- 
py36h9f0ad1d_1
```

I'm confused, because  I thought I was installing the 2.10.0 version. I install anyways, try to re-run my program and get a completely new error:

```
Headers are 1.10.4, library is 1.10.5
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
               HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
              Configured on: 2019-03-04
              Configured by: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
                Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
          Uname information: Windows
                   Byte sex: little-endian
         Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5
```

For the sake of space, I didn't include the whole error, but the whole error can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039297/how-to-install-hdf5-version-1-10-5-on-windows-10). The suggestion there is to do `pip install h5py --upgrade --no-dependencies --force`, but doing that leads to the same error. Another source (which I can't find right now), says there might be issues juggling both installs of pip and conda, so I run `pip uninstall h5py`, and the error persists. Then, using a suggestion [here](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/853), I run `conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.10.4` so that the library matches the header. I get stuck here, because even if I run my program again, I still get the same exact error. I don't understand why, shouldn't the library now be 1.10.4?

Other places have then suggested I uninstall, then reinstall. If I uninstall, I get the first error that I wrote down. when I reinstall, the cycle begins again. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried running using **hdf5=1.10.5** in this
`conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.10.5` instead of using **hdf5=1.10.4**?

You have 1.10.4 hdf5 library installed in a conda environment, some dependency of Tensorflow has newer hdf5 1.10.5 header files.

Try to ***update your conda hdf5 library to newer 1.10.5*** or alternatively use the command:

```
set HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=2
```

This should disable the warning but doesn't offer any warranty of correct execution, so ***It's better to update the hdf5*** library to the same version 1.10.5.

**If that was not enough, try also this workaround:**

First, try to remove the update for h5py 2.10.0 version revert it back to original and

**upgrade hdf5 to the 1.10.5 version via:**

`conda install -c anaconda hdf5=1.10.5`

**And uninstall a double** (if you have double h5py installed) **installation of h5py via:**

`conda uninstall h5py`

`pip uninstall h5py`

If you only have one then uninstall it

**Finally, upgrade to the hdf5 2.10.0 version again by**

`conda install -c conda-forge h5py`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Turns out that it was also installed via pip, not only pip3 and conda. So after uninstalling on conda, pip, and pip3, I installed it on conda and it works.