# Running the generate_tfrecords.py file won't generate the file

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tfrecord

Following the steps given [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-training-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api/), I am trying to create my own object detection program using the tensorflow object detection API (I am using Tensorflow 2.2.0. I cloned the repository in python with the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

I managed to label my images and generate the xml files as well using the LabelImg program. I also successfully created the csv files (images below) from the xml using the steps provided in the link above. However when running the `generate_tfrecords.py` file I got from [here](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py) from the object_detection directory as mentioned in the steps provided in the above mentioned link, I get the following issue when I run the code to generate the tfrecord - it just prints **Bye...** and does not generate the tfrecord file.

EDIT: The full output I am getting:

```
Warning! ***HDF5 library version mismatched error***
The HDF5 header files used to compile this application do not match
the version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked.
Data corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
This can happen when an application was compiled by one version of HDF5 but
linked with a different version of static or shared HDF5 library.
You should recompile the application or check your shared library related
settings such as 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'.
You can, at your own risk, disable this warning by setting the environment
variable 'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' to a value of '1'.
Setting it to 2 or higher will suppress the warning messages totally.
Headers are 1.10.2, library is 1.10.5
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================

General Information:
-------------------
                   HDF5 Version: 1.10.5
                  Configured on: 2019-03-04
                  Configured by: Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
                    Host system: Windows-10.0.17763
              Uname information: Windows
                       Byte sex: little-endian
             Installation point: C:/Program Files/HDF5

Compiling Options:
------------------
                     Build Mode:
              Debugging Symbols:
                        Asserts:
                      Profiling:
             Optimization Level:

Linking Options:
----------------
                      Libraries:
  Statically Linked Executables: OFF
                        LDFLAGS: /machine:x64
                     H5_LDFLAGS:
                     AM_LDFLAGS:
                Extra libraries:
                       Archiver:
                         Ranlib:

Languages:
----------
                              C: yes
                     C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                       CPPFLAGS:
                    H5_CPPFLAGS:
                    AM_CPPFLAGS:
                         CFLAGS:  /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3
                      H5_CFLAGS:
                      AM_CFLAGS:
               Shared C Library: YES
               Static C Library: YES

                        Fortran: OFF
               Fortran Compiler:
                  Fortran Flags:
               H5 Fortran Flags:
               AM Fortran Flags:
         Shared Fortran Library: YES
         Static Fortran Library: YES

                            C++: ON
                   C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe 19.16.27027.1
                      C++ Flags: /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc
                   H5 C++ Flags:
                   AM C++ Flags:
             Shared C++ Library: YES
             Static C++ Library: YES

                            JAVA: OFF
                   JAVA Compiler:

Features:
---------
                   Parallel HDF5: OFF
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes:
              Large Parallel I/O:
              High-level library: ON
                    Threadsafety: OFF
             Default API mapping: v110
  With deprecated public symbols: ON
          I/O filters (external):  DEFLATE DECODE ENCODE
                             MPE:
                      Direct VFD:
                         dmalloc:
  Packages w/ extra debug output:
                     API Tracing: OFF
            Using memory checker: OFF
 Memory allocation sanity checks: OFF
          Function Stack Tracing: OFF
       Strict File Format Checks: OFF
    Optimization Instrumentation:
Bye...
```

My `generate_tfrecords.py` code located at `<Path to Project>\models\research\object_detection\` is as follows:

```
"""
Usage:
  # From tensorflow/models/
  # Create train data:
  python generate_tfrecords.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record


  # Create test data:
  python generate_tfrecords.py --csv_input=images\test_labels.csv --image_dir=images\test --output_path=test.record
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import io
import os
from collections import namedtuple

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# TO-DO replace this with label map
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'a':
        return 1
    elif row_label == 'o':
        return 2
    else:
        return None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example

#EDIT
def main():
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))

#EDIT
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is how the directory looks like where I saved my training and testing data with the csv file located at `<Path to project>\models\research\`:

The train and test folders contain the image images and their respective .xml files.

[image: What my images directory looks like]

**EDIT:** This is how, for example, my `test_labels.csv` file looks like in case it helps:

[image: My test_labels.csv]

Any help or advice on why it won't generate the tfrecords will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running main() ?

Comment: @vodbeke I did try that, I put `main(_)` under `tf.app.run()` as well as removed the last 2 lines of code and kept `main(_)` as is, and still no result. Also not so sure, what the underscore in `def main(_)` means? I have been trying to understand it.

Comment: @vodbeke I have added an image of how my csv file looks like, in case it helps.

Comment: If you run with 'main()' there is no error code?

Comment: @vodbeke No. It gives the same stacktace as the above mentioned images, with Bye... at the end and does not create the the tfrecord. I tried different versions of code to generate the tfrecord, but still get the same issue. Could it be my tensorflow version? I am using 2.2.0rc2 in PyCharm

Comment: @vodbeke I also tried replacing the `FLAGS.output_path` and all with the absolute path, but still no result.

Comment: @vodbeke I've added the full stacktrace, in case it helps

Comment: Why not make your csv files relative to root directory and run tfrecords.py from root? Also could try downgrading to tf 2.1.0 as it is marked "stable"

Comment: @vodbeke I tried that as well and didn't work. I think the problem is that the HDF5 is conflicting. But it says headers found 1.10.4 but library 1.10.5 and when I install tensorflow, it installs both HDF5 and h5py. So I not sure where to get 1.10.5 from

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I managed to solve the problem by running the following command (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039297/how-to-install-hdf5-version-1-10-5-on-windows-10) answer) in the terminal:

```
pip install h5py --upgrade --no-dependencies --force
```

As well as changing the `FLAGS.output_path, FLAGS.image_dir and FLAGS.csv_input` to their absolute path string.